# Firebase: How to dynamically include modules under an HTTP function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to build an open-source library of some functionality on Firebase that people can clone and deploy to their own Firebase installation. Our functionality allows users to select a collection of modules with a JSON config file and then for each module chosen, our `functions/index.js` should load that functionality as HTTP functions. The file will look like this.

```
{modules: [{
    name: 'ModuleOne',
    options: {
        something: true
    }
}, {
    name: 'ModuleThree',
    options: {
        something: false
    }
}, {
    name: 'ModuleFour',
    options: {
        something: true
    }
}]}
```

The firebase cloud function HTTP URLs for this would be like:

https://us-central1-projectname-dev.cloudfunctions.net/OurProjectName/ModuleOne
https://us-central1-projectname-dev.cloudfunctions.net/OurProjectName/ModuleThree
https://us-central1-projectname-dev.cloudfunctions.net/OurProjectName/ModuleFour

**How can we create a firebase cloud function that allows us to dynamically select HTTP modules like this and enable them based on this configuration? We are OK with nesting the dynamic module paths under `OurProjectName` so maybe the we have a single function that uses a router under which we can dynamically add paths to to load our modules?**

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to do. What exactly is a "module" in this case?  A node module from npm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* what you're looking for here is essentially creating an HTTP function factory. This is actually not very difficult. You can do something like:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');

module.exports = function(options) {
  const app = express();
  options.modules.forEach(moduleConfig => {
    // add express routes for each module
  });
  return functions.https.onRequest(app);
};
```

Then developers would use your library like this:

```
const yourlib = require('yourlib');

exports.someFnName = yourlib({
  modules: [
    {name: 'ModuleOne', options: {}}
  ]
});
```